# Search and assign multiple strings with numpy.where or numpy.select in Python

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I am trying to do a conditional string assignment - if the cell contains the locations, assign the geo name into the cell next to it. I tried `np.where` and `np.select` and they tend to work on a single value assignment instead of multiple value assignment. Any suggestion I can do it through Numpy or there's an easier way to do this?

```
Europe = ['London', 'Paris', 'Berlin']
North_America = ['New York', 'Toroto', 'Boston']
Asia = ['Hong Kong', 'Tokyo', 'Singapore']

data = {'location':["London, Paris", "Hong Kong", "London, New York", "Singapore, Toroto", "Boston"]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

            location
0      London, Paris
1          Hong Kong
2   London, New York
3  Singapore, Toroto
4             Boston

# np.where approach
df['geo'] = np.where(( ( (df['location'].isin(Europe) ) ) | ( (df['location'].isin(North_America) ) ) ), 'Europe', 'North America')

# np.select approach
conditions = [
    df['location'].isin(Europe),
    df['location'].isin(North_America)
]
choices = ['Europe', 'North America']
df['geo'] = np.select(conditions, choices, default=0)
```

Expected output:

```
            location                    geo
0      London, Paris         Europe, Europe
1          Hong Kong                   Asia
2   London, New York  Europe, North America
3  Singapore, Toroto    Asia, North America
4             Boston          North America
```

Comment: You do not need so many parenthesis and you can put the value of `df['location']` to make the code a bit more readable/cleaner but this is a minor change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a mapping of each country -> area, then use `explode` and `map` to apply the mapping and finally, use `groupby` and `apply` to rebuild the list:

```
geo = {'Europe': Europe, 'North_America': North_America, 'Asia': Asia}
mapping = {country: area for area, countries in geo.items() for country in countries}

df['geo'] = df['location'].str.split(', ').explode().map(mapping) \
                          .groupby(level=0).apply(', '.join)
```

Output:

```
>>> df
            location                    geo
0      London, Paris         Europe, Europe
1          Hong Kong                   Asia
2   London, New York  Europe, North_America
3  Singapore, Toroto    Asia, North_America
4             Boston          North_America
```

Answer (score 1):

By using NumPy library together with python `for` loops we can get the results. At first we combine lists of country's cities together and then create another list named *continents* which length is the same as the created list of cities:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

continents = ["Europe"] * len(Europe) + ["North_America"] * len(North_America) + ["Asia"] * len(Asia)
countries = Europe + North_America + Asia
locations = data['location']
```

Then for each city, even for each in the combinations, we find its index in the created country list. Then we create a list for number of commas in each of that combinations for using to create the desired output with commas:

```
corsp = []
comma_nums = []
for i in locations:
    for j, k in enumerate(i.split(', ')):
        corsp.append(np.where(np.array(countries) == k)[0][0])
    comma_nums.append(j)
```

*continents* list will be reordered and modified by created index list. Then its arguments combined in list format as the combination style which where in *locations*, and then the lists convert to strings as they are needed for the output:

```
reordered_continents = [continents[i] for i in corsp]

mod_continents = []
iter = 0
f = 1
for i in comma_nums:
    mod_continents.append(reordered_continents[iter:i + f])
    iter = i + f
    f = iter + 1

for i, j in enumerate(mod_continents):
    if len(j) > 1:
        for k in j:
            mod_continents[i] = ', '.join(j)
    else:
        mod_continents[i] = ''.join(j)

df['geo'] = mod_continents
```